# How to write an if else statement in R when the condition has a length greater than 1

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write an if else statement within a for loop in R where if i == any range of values in a vector, do this, else, do something else. I am aware that when the condition in an if statement has a length greater than 1, only the first value is used, however, I was wondering if there was a way around this since the vector I am using is extremely long (180 values) and it would be incredibly messy to write an individual if statement for each condition within the vector. An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is typed out below. Is there any way around using only the first value in a condition?

```
    example<-c(1,2,3,4)
    z<-c()
    for (i in 1:10)
    {
      if (i==example) #if i == any of the values in example
      {
        z<-c(z,0) #add a 0 to the vector z
      }else {z<-c(z,1)} #else add a 1
    }

    #resulting vector should have four zeros and six ones
```

Comment: Try using the `%in%` operator. i.e. `if (i %in% example)`

Answer (score 1):

You are making things more difficult by using a loop:

```
x <- 1:10
example <- 1:4
(z <- ifelse(x %in% example, 0, 1))
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: For the actual code I am building a loop is necessary, the example provided here was just meant to demonstrate that I needed a way to override the "condition is greater than length 1" warning. The %in% operator works perfectly. However, I appreciate your input.